# Refactoring inner loops with lots of dependencies between levels

Tags: java, c#, for-loop, nested, convention

I am having the following preudo-code

```
using (some web service/disposable object)
{
    list1 = service.get1();

    list2 = service.get2();

    for (item2 in list2)
    {
        list3 = service.get3(depending on item2);

        for (item3 in list3)
        {
            list4 = service.get4(depending on item3 and list1);

            for (item4 in list4)
            {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

where the entire code has, let's say 500 lines with lots of logic inside `for` statements. The problem is refactoring this into a readable and maintainable code and as a best practice for similar situations. Here are the possible solutions I found so far.

**1: Split into methods**
Considering we extract each `for` into its own method, to improve readability, we end up with method2, method3 and method4. Each method has its own parameters and dependencies, which is good, except for method4. Method4 depends on list1 which means that list1 must be passed to methods 2 and 3 as well. From my opinion, this becomes unreadable. Any developer looking at method2 will realize there is no point for list1 inside it, so he has to look down the chain until method4 to actually realize the dependency -> inefficient. Then, what happens if list4 or item4 changes and no longer needs a dependency on list1 ? I have to remove list1 parameter for method4 (which should be done, naturally) but also for methods 2 and 3 (out of the scope of change) -> again inefficient. Another side effect is that, in case on lots of dependencies and multiple levels, the number of parameters passed down will quickly increase. Think what happens if list4 also depends on list11, list12 and list13, all created at the level of list1.

**2: Keep a long single method**
The advantage is that every list and item can access every parent list and item, which makes the further changes a one-liner. If list4 no longer depends on list1, just remove/replace the code, without changing anything else. Obviously, the problem is that the method is couple hundred lines, which we all know it's not good.

**3. Best of both worlds ?**
The idea is to split into methods only the inner logical part of each `for`. This way the main method will decrease and we gain readability and possibly maintainability. Leaving the `for` in the main method, we are still able to access each dependency as a one-liner. We end up with something like this:

```
for (item2 in list2)
{
    compute();

    list3 = service.get3(depending on item2);

    for (item3 in list3)
    {
        compute(item2, eventually item1)

        list4 = service.get4(depending on item3 and list1);

        for (item4 in list4)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

But there is another problem. How do you name those `compute` methods in order to be readable ? Let's say that I have a local variable `instanceA` or type `ClassA` which I populate from item2. Class A contains a property named LastItem4 which needs to keep, let's say, last item4 in order of creation date or whatever. If I use compute to create the `instanceA`, then this compute is only partial. Because LastItem4 property needs to be populated on item4 level, in a different compute method. So how to I call these 2 compute methods to suggest what I am actually doing ? Tough answer, in my opinion.

**4. #region**
Leave a single long method but use regions. This is a feature strictly used in some programming languages and seems to me like a patch, not as a best practice, but maybe it's just me.

I would like to know how would you do this refactoring ? Be aware that it may be even more complex than that. The fact that is a service is a bit misleading, the idea is that i don't really like using disposable objects as method parameters, because you don't know the intent without reading the actual method code. But I was expecting this in comments since others may feel otherwise.

For the sake of example, let's assume that the service is a 3rd party one, without the possibility to change the way it works.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't make sense from the pseudo code given. I can't understand where this ends, what you do after looping all items? All I can see is it loops and loops and loops. What it  does finally? Can you give me one real example which makes sense without the pseudo code?

Comment: @sriram: For example, export data from a web service into your own entities. Or just do "select" statements in order to populate some UI models. The source entities are not necessarily the same as destination entities. Destination entities could be aggregates, or only some of the items based on some logic. I didn't add such code because I would have cluttered the question and led you away from actual problem.

Comment: Maybe It's me alone, but I don't understand what you mean by *depending on item3 and list1* etc. If we assume something and answer you'll say not like that I mean something different, and that's a waste of time for you and us. So I expect you to provide a compilable code which makes sense. I don't need a real production code. Some stub code which shows the problem. Show a blank definition of `Service` with the method signatures and how your client code loop ends. I'll try to answer.

Comment: @sriram: I don't have any service. I told you it can be anything that provides a tree-like structure that need nested loops. By "depending on..." i mean that for example: get3(item2.SomeProperty, item2.OtherProperty, list1.Count, list1[0].Anything). It just depends on their values, whatever they are. I can't explain any more than that. If I provide you a real example, you WILL answer strictly to that example, so it won't answer my question.

Comment: Read [Clean Code](http://www.amazon.de/Clean-Code-Handbook-Software-Craftsmanship/dp/0132350882/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1423745182&sr=8-2&keywords=clean+code).

Comment: @EagleBeak: That was the final resource I consulted before posting this :). But couldn't find anything close to this situation.

Comment: @Tejveer Then read [Refactoring](http://www.amazon.com/Refactoring-Improving-Design-Existing-Code/dp/0201485672)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up with using solution 3 described in the question, in combination with DTOs. This is not necessarily the best choice, but it is better than the rest in terms or readability, flexibility and scaling.

Comment: Great to hear you found an adequate solution for your problem! As I said, it depends on your problem domain, and unfortunately there is no magical solution and no silver bullet.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're looking for a general answer rather than a specific answer. Key to general answer is Separating the responsibilities and striving hard to achieve *Single responsibility principle*.

Let me start with the point that your method does *toooooooo many things*. This much stuff ideally a class also shouldn't do. It should be done with the help of group of classes.

Robert C.Martin used to say "Classes tends to hide in methods", which is the case here. If your method is big you can refactor it to smaller methods but if a local variable is needed throughout the method, probably that method should go in its own class.

If you need some fields to be access together, they have to live together(I mean in a same type). So all your List1, List2, List3, List4 should live in a class, not as method parameters whatsoever.

Given that you can't modify the `Service` class (assuming it is the third party API). That's fine, you can always create your own class which wraps the aforementioned service.

So you'll essentially a class something like the following:

```
public class ServiceWrapper
{
    private IList<string> list1;
    private IList<string> list2;
    private IList<string> list3;
    private IList<string> list4;

    private readonly Service1 service;
    public ServiceWrapper(Service1 service)
    {
        this.service = service;
    }

    public SomeClass GetSomething()
    {
        list1 = service.Get1();
        list2 = service.Get2();

        foreach (var item2 in list2)
        {
            PopulateMore(item2);
        }

        return result;//Return some computed result
    }

    private void PopulateMore(string item2)
    {
        list3 = service.Get3(item2);

        foreach (var item3 in list3)
        {
            PopulateEvenMore(item3);
        }
    }

    private void PopulateEvenMore(string item3)
    {
        list4 = service.Get4(item3);

        foreach (var item4 in list4)
        {
            //And so on
        }
    }
}
```

Given your service looks something like this

```
public class Service1 : IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public IList<string> Get1()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public IList<string> Get2()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public IList<string> Get3(string item2)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public IList<string> Get4(string item3)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

So your very long method becomes very small now.

```
public void YourVeryLongMethodBecomesVerySmall()
{
    using (Service1 service = new Service1())
    {
        SomeClass result = new ServiceWrapper(service).GetSomething();
    }
}
```

As you said in comments if you have some other responsibilities also inside those methods you need to separate those responsibilities and move it in its own class. For example if you want to parse something, that should go inside some `Parser` class and `ServiceWrapper` should use the parser to get the job done (ideally with some abstraction and loose coupling).

You should extract methods and classes as much as you can so that it can't make sense to extract anymore.

Comment: Yes, this is similar to my first solution of splitting into methods. How do you comment upon DrKoch's answer and EagleBeak's reply ?

Comment: DrKoch has a right idea but his answer isn't complete because he says to make a field, but didn't said in which class etc. If thread safety is a concern you'll have to address this by locking etc, My question is why can't you create new instance for each thread?. Calling methods in wrong order isn't a problem because all those methods are private, `GetSomething` is the only public method which accesses the private members. It knows how to call them. I think I've answered EagleBeak's reply with the context of my answer. If he disagrees he can always comment down here.

Comment: You named the class ServiceWrapper so I understand your intention. What if there are some other public methods like GetSomethingElse ? Does it mean i need to declare all those service entities as private members as well ? That would be a real mess. I also find it hard to maintain and scale this code. I think method name is not enough to describe the dependencies it has. You will always have to read the method body in order to understand what it does and what members it uses. Besides that, the list1-4 do not necessarily form and entity, so I think I would break SRP with this class.

Comment: If you think that `GetSomethingElse` makes sense to go inside `ServiceWrapper`, let it go, otherwise it should go in another class. Also if you need to access the group of entities together you need a new class which holds those group of entities as properties. If you did so, you don't have to declare all the entities as fields, you can simply use newly created class as field and access its properties.

Comment: That's exactly the point. list1-4 do NOT necessarily belong to a class. Personally, I think at them as temporary storage classes that I'm stuck with using, because of web reference. Else, I would have to parse JSON or XML or SOAP or whatever service sends. Even SOAP parsing would make more sense than those classes grouped in a class. But, of course, is not acceptable because of lots of reasons we are aware of. How would I call that class anyway... GetSomethingResult ?

Comment: Anyway even if that doesn't belong to new class you could give them a class, if they are temporary objects used just to transfer data between objects they do have a name called [Data Transfer Object](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataTransferObject.html) You can use `SomethingDTO`  or `SomethingResult`. I've seen people using both of the terms.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, it depends on your problem domain and how much you can split your method in verbs that make sense, but generally option 3 is the best choice accordingly with my experience.

About #region, do not use it. It is best used for separating generated code vs your code. Using region to "structure" your code is like putting garbage under the carpet, it is still there and you can feel it.

One more thing to note is, probably you are facing a collections related problem and a good library like Guava (google-collections) would help you a lot. Also using Java 8 lambda features or .Net LINQ could help you rewrite your code and make it more expressive.

- Guava: https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/
- Java 8 Streams vs .Net LINQ: http://blog.informatech.cr/2013/03/24/java-streams-preview-vs-net-linq/

Answer (score 0):

Don't use regions. They don't help if you print, if you use CodeMap and so on.

Make list1, list2, .. private class variables.

Create a method for each `for()` loop:

```
private void method3()
{
    for (item3 in list3)
    {
        list4 = service.get4(depending on item3 and list1);
        method4();
    }
}
```

Throw in a few good comments for each method...

This has the additional benefit to allow for nice unit tests of each `methodX()`

Comment: I don't think this is good advice for two reasons. **1.** You add state to your class where it's not needed. This is often fragile, because it's possible that you break it by calling methods in the wrong order, etc. Don't even try to call this code from different threads. **2.** adding comments introduces more problems than it solves. [This blog](http://apdevblog.com/comments-in-code/) explains why. A more in-depth explanation can be found in [this book](http://www.amazon.de/Clean-Code-Handbook-Software-Craftsmanship/dp/0132350882/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1423745182&sr=8-2&keywords=clean+code).

Comment: Doesn't that break SRP ? I mean they do have dependencies between them, but they do not necessarily form an entity. For example, think list2 is clients and list3 is statistics. And i kinda agree with EagleBeak.